# DataTable Modal TableTool Buttons Not Working

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-modal, tabletools

In the past, I have successfully created DataTables that display dynamic data. I have also added the TableTools plug-in to be able to export the data to CSV, Excel, Copy/Pase, etc.

However, when I add a bootstrap modaldialog box and place the table inside, the buttons do not work (except the print button ... that does). This is the case for all web browsers.

Here is a scaled-down jsFiddle of my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1210/

**HTML CODE**

```
  <h3>Modal TableTool Example</h3>

  <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
  <div>
    <a href="#myModal1" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Modal</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3>Standard Selectpickers</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

      <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="tblResults">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Event Code</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<style>
```

**JS CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var dataSet = [
    ["1", "2016/03/01", "Test 1"],
    ["2", "2016/03/02", "Test 2"],
    ["3", "2016/03/03", "Test 3"],
    ["4", "2016/03/04", "Test 4"],
    ["5", "2016/03/05", "Test 1"],
    ["6", "2016/03/06", "Test 2"],
    ["7", "2016/03/07", "Test 3"],
    ["8", "2016/03/08", "Test 4"],
    ["9", "2016/03/09", "Test 1"],
    ["10", "2016/03/10", "Test 2"],
    ["11", "2016/03/11", "Test 3"],
    ["12", "2016/03/12", "Test 4"],
  ];

  var table = $('#tblResults').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [{
      title: "ID"
    }, {
      title: "Date"
    }, {
      title: "Event Code"
    }]
  });

  var tableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(table, {
    'sSwfPath': 'http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf',
    'aButtons': ['copy',
      'csv', {
        'sExtends': 'xls',
        sFileName: '*.xls'
      },
      'pdf',
      'print'
    ],
  });

  $(tableTools.fnContainer()).insertBefore('#tblResults_wrapper');

});
```

Any help would be appreciated.